# Sort array in array by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

How to sort array in array, by date, if I have array like this:

now array:

```
[{place: "TEST", date: "2018-01-25 17:25", quantity: "12"}, {place: "TEST2", date: "2018-01-24 17:25", quantity: "2"}]
```

sorting array

```
[{place: "TEST2", date: "2018-01-24 17:25", quantity: "2"}, {place: "TEST", date: "2018-01-25 17:25", quantity: "12"}]
```

Comment: meaning you only want an array that contains date?

Comment: Yes, I want sort array by date.

array
[{place: "TEST", date: "2018-01-25 17:25", quantity: "12"}, {place: "TEST2", date: "2018-01-24 17:25", quantity: "2"}]

sorting array:
[{place: "TEST2", date: "2018-01-24 17:25", quantity: "2"}, {place: "TEST", date: "2018-01-25 17:25", quantity: "12"}]

Comment: simple web search for *"javascript sort array by date"* should have given you numerous results